# Adding Fragaria framework to Xcode

Tags: xcode, macos, build, linker, frameworks

I am trying to install the latest version of mugginsoft's Fragaria framework. My project already has some CocoaPods and static C libraries, the project targets macOS 10.12 and is written in Objective-C.

I cloned the repo from github, but it turned out there was no install guide. I did exactly what the other question on SO suggested:

1. Build the framework from source. I did so by opening the .xcodeproj file, changing target to Fragaria framework, choosing Product->Build For->Running and copying the resulting .framework file to a known location from the DerivedData location Xcode put it in.
2. Project->Targets->My Target->General->Linked Frameworks & Libraries->Other->Choose Fragaria.framework
3. Add it to copy files build phase, copying to Frameworks directory

It did not work. Although the .framework file could be seen inside the Frameworks folder with all its headers and the views from the framework are recognised in IB, building the project yields a disappointing `Fragaria/Fragaria.h not found`.

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually resorted to using a custom Fragaria podspec, which can be found on CocoaPods' macOS app github repository.